# Jest mock pdfmake and fs.createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am very new to Jest and unit testing in general. I am trying to generate a test for a piece of code that essentially uses pdfmake and fs.createWriteStream in order to create and write to a pdf file

As I am reading tutorials - and getting confused a bit as it's info I am not used to - I have tried to put together a couple of things. An fs.js module to try and get the writestream mocked. About the pdfmake I am not very sure - could i perhaps skip that and assume I have a target file and therefore mock just the stream creation?

```
describe('createWriteStream', () => {
  const MOCK_FILE_INFO = {
    '/path/to/file1.pdf': 'console.log("file1 pdf contents");'
  };
})
```

Something like the above?

And then just have a result as success for the fs.createWriteStream?

The original code looks something like:

```
let pdfDoc = new pdfPrinter({
  Roboto: {
    normal: new Buffer(require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js').pdfMake.vfs['Roboto-Regular.ttf'], 'base64')
  }
}).createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
pdfDoc.end();
```

I understand is not a lot of info but I guess if someone is very aware of unit testing might know how to best shape this. Thanks

Comment: Where does `path` come from? I would avoid mocking the file system interactions, that behavior is not hard to test. Structuring the code is such a way that you have control over `path` during testing would be ideal. Once you can control `path` in the tests you can verify that the file is being generated. I would reserve mocking for complex interactions that are difficult to test in isolation, like database access or requests to external systems.

Comment: Thanks Jake appreciate your response! Might start with path then and see where the jest documentation reading takes me :)